# Node.JS - Multiple stream.writes not working

Tags: node.js, fs

Folks,

I'm attempting to write multiple times to a stream using fs & nodejs but when the stream ends and the file is saved, it only contains the first "stream.write()".

```
var csvToSql = function (array, filename, callback) {
var outputFileName = "./output/" + filename + ".sql"
fs.writeFile(outputFileName, "", function(err) {console.log(err)});
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName);
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    stream.write("USE CPC3;\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log("wr");
        stream.write("UPDATE DEAL\n");
        stream.write("SET third_party_beacons = '[{\"label\":\"" + array[i].label + "\",\"mime_type\":\"image\\/*\",\"protocol\"=" + array[i].protocol + "\", \"type\"=\"" + array[i].type + "\",\"url\"=\"" + array[i].url + "\"}]\n");
        stream.write("WHERE deal_id = " + array[i].deal_id + "\n\n");
    };
    stream.end();
    return callback(outputFileName);
});

};
```

So the output file looks like:

```
USE CPC3;
```

What gives?

Comment: Do you see `wr` on console?

Comment: Your code works for me, check the contents of your array.

Comment: I do see `wr` appear for each item in my array which is strange.

Comment: Can you bind 'end' and 'error' events and print something there.